# Texto não fica em cima ao lado das imagens

Tags: html5, css3

Boa tarde, estou a construir um site, e precisava que o texto ficasse ao lado da logo da AETTR, mas em cima e não em baixo, alguém sabe como resolver?

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.logos-container{
    background: #ccc;
}
.logomin{
    width: 245px;
}
.logoaetr{
    width: 145px;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="logos-container">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="https://i.ibb.co/njPs6xJ/min.png" class="logomin" alt="Ministerio da Educação" /></li>
                <li><img src="https://i.ibb.co/mcKb85g/aetr.png" class="logoaetr" alt="Agrupamento de Escolas Tomaz Ribeiro" /></li>
                <li><h2>Autenticação</h2></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/HVzp8mm/Sem-T-tulo.png onde se encontra a caixa preta, eu quero isto para depois simplesmente poder aplicar um margin top ao texto e alinhar ao meio mais ou menos em relação as imagens

Comment: Sim eu sei, eu quero colocar o texto "Autenticação" la em cima para depois simplesmente poder aplicar um margin top ao texto e alinhar mais ou menos ao meio em relação as imagens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque a propriedade `vertical-align: top` na terceira `<li>` da lista:

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.logos-container{
    background: #ccc;
}
.logomin{
    width: 245px;
}
.logoaetr{
    width: 145px;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.logos-container ul li:nth-child(3){
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="logos-container">
   <ul>
       <li><img src="https://i.ibb.co/njPs6xJ/min.png" class="logomin" alt="Ministerio da Educação" /></li>
       <li><img src="https://i.ibb.co/mcKb85g/aetr.png" class="logoaetr" alt="Agrupamento de Escolas Tomaz Ribeiro" /></li>
       <li><h2>Autenticação</h2></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

O seletor `.logos-container ul li:nth-child(3)` pega a terceira `<li>` da lista dentro da div com classe `.logos-container`.

Comment: Obrigado, eu tinha pensado em colocar margin-top: -5px; mas sei que isso é gambiarra e que provavelmente n iria funcionar.

Comment: Sim, seria uma gambiarra mesmo :D